# How to update status in other table?

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have two table `inspections` and `requisitions`.

In requisitions table has a field `status` and value `0` default. I want to when a user press submit `status` update to 1.

**inspections table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('inspections', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('requisition_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('encouragement_data')->nullable(true);
        $table->text('infraction_data')->nullable(true);
                $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('requisition_id')->references('id')->on('requisitions')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

**requisitions table**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('requisitions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('school_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('type');
        $table->boolean('status')->default(0);
        $table->string('date');
        $table->boolean('approved');
                $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('school_id')->references('id')->on('schools')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

**InspectionController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $inspection = new Inspection();
    $inspection->infraction_data = $request->infractions;
    $inspection->encouragement_data = $request->encouragement;
    $inspection->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $inspection->requisition_id = 1;
    $inspection->update()->requisitions->staus = 1;
    $inspection->save();
    return redirect()->route('inspection-results.index');
}
```

**Inspection.php**

```
public function requisitions()
{
    $this->belongsTo(Requisition::class);
}
```

Comment: can you share your blade.php file which had user submit button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In blade.php

set the following code segment to user submit button

```
@foreach($tasks as $task)
<a href="/status/{{$task_>id}}" class="btn-btn-primary">submit</a>
@endforeach
```

In web.php

```
Route::get('/status/{id},'InspectionController@updateStatus');
```

In InspectionController.php

Create following method.

```
public function updateStatus($id){
$task=requisitionsModelName::find($id);
$task->status=1;
$task->save();
return redirect()->back();
}
```

In requisitions table

```
$data=requisitionsModelName::all();
return view('relevantViewname')->with('tasks',$data);
```